# Pictures open over the whole site with FancyBox

Tags: jquery, fancybox

I'm trying to use FancyBox, so I added the folder "fancybox" to my homepage, added the js-scripts and such as on the fancybox homepage described but the only thing that happen when I click on a thumbnail is that the picture opens over the whole site with normal URL...

So what is wrong?

I tried to change the classes of the `<a>` tags, but it doesn't work and so I don't really know what's wrong.

I am sorry that I cannot describe the problem better, but there is no "error message" on the site. The only error message I see is in the Firefox console:

> TypeError: $(...).attr(...).fancybox is not a function

and if I delete the function `.attr()` then I get this error:

> TypeError: $(...).fancybox is not a function

The valid code:

```
<head>
<!-- ---------- Fancy-Box Includes ----------  -->

<!-- Add jQuery library -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>

<!-- Add mousewheel plugin (this is optional) -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="/fancybox/lib/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.6.pack.js"></script>

<!-- Add fancyBox -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.5" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?v=2.1.5"></script>

<!-- Optionally add helpers - button, thumbnail and/or media -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.css?v=1.0.5" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.js?v=1.0.5"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-media.js?v=1.0.6"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.css?v=1.0.7" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="/fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js?v=1.0.7"></script>
<!-- ---------- End Fancy-Box Includes ---------- -->

<!-- ---------- Use Fancy-Box ---------- -->
<script type="text/javascript">
$(".fancybox")
.attr('rel', 'gallery')
.fancybox({
    beforeShow: function () {
        /* Disable right click */
        $.fancybox.wrap.bind("contextmenu", function (e) {
                return false; 
        });
    }
});
</script>
<!-- ---------- End Use Fancy-Box ---------- -->
</head>
```

and in the body-tag - the normal navigation stuff and so on, and then this table:

```
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" summary="Image gallery">
<tbody>
<tr class="row_0 row_first even">
<td class="col_0 col_first" style="width:25%;">
<div class="image_container">
<a class="fancybox" href="./media/picture01.jpg" title="picture01"><img src="./media/./media/picture01.jpg" width="150" /></a>
</div>
</td>

<!-- ..... more pictures ..... -->

</tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Run the page with the firebug console open and the see if any javascript error occurs or not, if it does let me know that exact error.

Comment: TypeError: $(...).attr(...).fancybox is not a function

Comment: @ManuelWeitzel - please add that error description to your question.

Comment: most likely fancybox is not being loaded, check your paths or the source code and click on the calls to fancybox

Comment: oh thx really !! i didn't update the pathes the site searched fancybox in the root of the webspace ... :(

Comment: try to define $(".fancybox")
.attr('rel', 'gallery')
.fancybox({.... inside $document.ready

Answer (score 0, accepted):

PHP doesn't know fancybox as a function because fancybox is in a folder named "fancybox" but not in root on webspace - so the right code have to look like this:

```
<head>
<!-- ---------- Fancy-Box Includes ----------  -->

<!-- Add jQuery library -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>

<!-- Add mousewheel plugin (this is optional) -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="./fancybox/lib/jquery.mousewheel-3.0.6.pack.js"></script>

<!-- Add fancyBox -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.css?v=2.1.5" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="./fancybox/source/jquery.fancybox.pack.js?v=2.1.5"></script>

<!-- Optionally add helpers - button, thumbnail and/or media -->
<link rel="stylesheet" href="./fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.css?v=1.0.5" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="./fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-buttons.js?v=1.0.5"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="./fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-media.js?v=1.0.6"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="./fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.css?v=1.0.7" type="text/css" media="screen" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="./fancybox/source/helpers/jquery.fancybox-thumbs.js?v=1.0.7"></script>
<!-- ---------- End Fancy-Box Includes ---------- -->

<!-- ---------- Use Fancy-Box ---------- -->
<script type="text/javascript">
$(".fancybox") 
.attr('rel', 'gallery')
.fancybox({
    beforeShow: function () {
        /* Disable right click */
        $.fancybox.wrap.bind("contextmenu", function (e) {
                return false; 
        });
    }
});
</script>
<!-- ---------- End Use Fancy-Box ---------- -->
</head>
```